# Which user is actually loaded when we set Load User Profile = True to the application pool identity?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

Among the local user accounts on the server, which one is loaded when I set `Load User Profile` to `True` on the application pool identity?

I need to know this because my application need to attach database file using `User Instance = True`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The DefaultAppPool unless you change the user profile